# SMTP external connection telnet not working

Tags: postfix, smtp

I recently installed postfix , openssl , configured SMTP and all records on cloudflare but for some reason I cant find out It does not work

When I try to connect using telnet

```
[root@reputation ~]# telnet reputation.help
Trying 104.219.235.10...
telnet: connect to address 104.219.235.10: Connection refused
```

Here is mine main.cf

```
[root@reputation ~]# cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
myhostname = reputation.help
mydomain = reputation.help
myorigin = $mydomain
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.crt
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol         = 2
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Also master.cf

```
[root@reputation ~]# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Here is output from netstat -pln

```
[root@reputation ~]# netstat -pln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4695/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4695/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2171/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4695/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2171/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8891          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1648/opendkim
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8893          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1996/opendmarc
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      4695/master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2719/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      4695/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      2171/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      999/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      4695/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      2171/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           2171/named
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                2171/named
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           787/NetworkManager
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67671    4695/master          public/cleanup
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67674    4695/master          public/qmgr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67678    4695/master          private/tlsmgr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67681    4695/master          private/rewrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67684    4695/master          private/bounce
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67687    4695/master          private/defer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67690    4695/master          private/trace
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67693    4695/master          private/verify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67696    4695/master          public/flush
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67699    4695/master          private/proxymap
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67702    4695/master          private/proxywrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67705    4695/master          private/smtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67708    4695/master          private/relay
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67711    4695/master          public/showq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67714    4695/master          private/error
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67717    4695/master          private/retry
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67720    4695/master          private/discard
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67723    4695/master          private/local
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67726    4695/master          private/virtual
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67729    4695/master          private/lmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67732    4695/master          private/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67735    4695/master          private/scache
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2952     1/systemd            /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2987     1/systemd            /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2479     1/systemd            /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14531    1/systemd            /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3047     1/systemd            /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3049     1/systemd            /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     67667    4695/master          public/pickup
```

I cant figure out what is problem on mailx It works without any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When using telnet, you need to specify the port number. Otherwise, it will connect to the default port for the telnet protocol, 23. To test that a mail server is responding to SMTP requests, you should specify port 25:

```
telnet reputation.help 25
```

Make sure that the hostname resolves to the IP address of the network interface that Postfix is listening on (should be all according to `main.cf`), ensure that the network interface is up and that Port 25 on the mail server is not filtered by a firewall. After successfully connecting to Port 25, check the server's mail log for relevant entries.

Comment: [root@reputation ~]# telnet reputation.help 25
Trying 104.219.235.10...
Connected to reputation.help.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @SuadHalilović That sounds like there's no service listening to Port 25 on 104.219.235.10. I've edited my answer to include some troubleshooting pointers.

Answer (score 0):

can you telnet to known working servers?  For example, `host gmail.com` gives a few mx servers, then telnet to `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` if this fails it's likely a firewall upstream from your isp.  Test from a server that CAN open tcp/25, like a VPS that does not restrict outbound ports or a business class network.  You can also use 3rd party tools like https://www.wormly.com/test-smtp-server, if the information you provided is actual. it looks like a firewall/socket issue on your server or upstream firewall out of your control, **MANY VPS SERVERS REQUIRE SPECIAL PERMISSION TO OPEN PORT 25 FOR ABUSE PURPOSES.**

`Resolving hostname...
Connecting...
Connection: opening to reputation.help:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                 )
Message sending failed.`

mailx locally wouldn't have an issue with upstream firewalls.